# Recursive Query and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am stuck with a query that is using recursive and wondering if you guys can help me out.

I have this query below and it is based on the ShipQuantity, then it lists the number of records.  For example, mfgPN "ABC123" has a ShipQuantity of 4, it will list 4 records with a number 1,2,3, 4.

```
WITH feedInfo
AS (
    SELECT df1.RecID, MfgPN, LinkID, ShipQuantity, 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df1
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND df1.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT df2.RecID, df2.MfgPN, df2.LinkID, df2.ShipQuantity, feedInfo.number + 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df2
    INNER JOIN feedInfo ON df2.RecID = feedInfo.RecID
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND number < feedInfo.ShipQuantity
    AND df2.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')
)
Select feedInfo.*
From feedInfo
OPTION (maxrecursion 20000);
```

Let's say the result is

```
RecID   MfgPN   LinkID  ShipQuantity    Number 
101     ABC1    L11111  4               1
102     ABC1    L11111  4               2
103     ABC1    L11111  4               3
104     ABC1    L11111  4               4
105     ABC2    L22222  2               1
106     ABC2    L22222  2               2
```

Now, I have another table "EXT_DistributorFeedDetail" where it may contain serial# (some part# have serial# and some part# don't have).  This table has only two columns: (1) LinkID and (2)SerialNo.  Like this:

```
EXT_DistributorFeedDetail
LinkID  SerialNo
L22222  S999999 
L22222  S888888
```

I would like to join the feedInfo with EXT_DistributorFeedDetail table to get the result like this:

```
RecID   MfgPN   LinkID  ShipQuantity    Number  Serial
101     ABC1    L11111  4               1       NULL
102     ABC1    L11111  4               2       NULL
103     ABC1    L11111  4               3       NULL
104     ABC1    L11111  4               4       NULL
105     ABC2    L22222  2               1       S99999
106     ABC2    L22222  2               2       S88888
```

Any expert out there can help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Does the order of the Serial number in the final result matter?  you have them ordered desc in the expected result but is this going to always be the case?

Comment: The order of serial number is not matter in the result.  The order of Number column should be in order 1,2,3,... then restart 1,2,3.. for the next Part# if possible... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to match up the LinkID and Number from the recursive query to the LinkID and a Row Number in the `EXT_DistributorFeedDetail` table

```
WITH feedInfo
AS (
    SELECT df1.RecID, MfgPN, LinkID, ShipQuantity, 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df1
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND df1.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT df2.RecID, df2.MfgPN, df2.LinkID, df2.ShipQuantity, feedInfo.number + 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df2
    INNER JOIN feedInfo ON df2.RecID = feedInfo.RecID
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND number < feedInfo.ShipQuantity
    AND df2.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')
)
Select  fi.*,
        dfd.SerialNo [Serial]
From    feedInfo fi
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LinkID ORDER BY SerialNo) rn, 
                   FROM EXT_DistributorFeedDetail) dfd 
           ON dfd.LinkID = fi.LinkID AND dfd.rn = fi.Number
OPTION (maxrecursion 20000);
```

Depending on what order you want the serial numbers in the EXT_DistributorFeedDetail table to be you would need to change the order by in the Window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LinkID ORDER BY SerialNo)`  if you take out the Order by the it would be random and could change.

Comment: Thank you so much.  (I ran into an error first time, but after removed the comma (,) after "rn, From EXT_..."). It works perfect!

Comment: Why the condition "WHERE 1=1" ?

Comment: @BinuVijayan  not sure why they are using `where 1=1`  typically it is used when you are building a dynamic where clause.  you add `where 1=1` then everything after that just has to start with AND or OR, and you dont have to keep checking if you have already added a condition

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to join the SerialNo in descending order for the number. You can do this by changing the last part of the query to this:

```
with feedinfo as (
  ....
)

select f.*, e.*
from feedinfo f 
left join (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by linkid order by serialno desc) 
    from ext_distributorfeeddetail
) e on f.linkid = e.linkid and f.number = e.rn
option (maxrecursion 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `left join` on the `EXT_DistributorFeedDetail` table to extract `serial` column. Note that for each recid in the output the serial column will be repeated as many times as the number of entries per linkid in the EXT_DistributorFeedDetail table.

```
    WITH feedInfo AS 
    (
    SELECT df1.RecID, MfgPN, LinkID, ShipQuantity, 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df1
    WHERE df1.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT df2.RecID, df2.MfgPN, df2.LinkID, df2.ShipQuantity, 
    feedInfo.number + 1 AS Number 
    FROM EXT_DistributorFeed df2
    INNER JOIN feedInfo ON df2.RecID = feedInfo.RecID
    WHERE number < feedInfo.ShipQuantity
    AND df2.mfgPN IN ('ABC1', 'ABC2')
    )
    Select feedInfo.*, e.serial
    From feedInfo
    left join EXT_DistributorFeedDetail e
    on e.linkid = feedinfo.linkid
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but that will take forever and list hundred of thousand records because the LinkID is repeating.. I guess.